# "twoSum" solution and Big O Time Complexity explanation

Tags: java, big-o

I was messing around with possible "twoSum" solutions because I'm pretty bored... Anyways I'm pretty new to "Big O Time Complexity", and I was trying to figure out the time complexity of my program.

Now I don't assume my solution is at all polished or better, I was just wanting some help finding out the time complexity of it. I am very new to BIG(O) so don't dog on my skills... you can roast my code if you wish.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {5, 3, 4, 1, 5, 2, 1, 6, 3, 2};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(twoSum(array, 6)));
    }

    public static int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int oldValue = 0;
        int newValue;
        int currentValue;

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            currentValue = i;
            if (currentValue != 0) { // so oldValue never causes an exception
                oldValue = i - 1;
            }
            newValue = i + 1;

            if ((nums[currentValue] + nums[oldValue]) == target) {
                return new int[]{currentValue, oldValue};
            }

            if ((nums[currentValue] + nums[newValue]) == target) {
                return new int[]{currentValue, newValue};
            }

            if ((nums[newValue] + nums[oldValue]) == target) {
                return new int[]{newValue, oldValue};
            }
        }

        return new int[]{0, 0}; // we print out 0 0 if we can't find a solution
    }
```

This really won't have an ANSWER, as I don't know how time complexity works fully (as of right now) all I am asking for is someone to help me with an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you are trying to find 2 consecutive numbers in an array  whose sum is equal to the target

Firstly, you don't need to use oldValue and newValue, since when `currentValue = 2`, `oldValue` will be equal to `1`, which is basically checking the same pair of numbers as when `currentValue = 1` and `newValue = 2`. The better version of your code should be:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {5, 3, 4, 1, 5, 2, 1, 6, 3, 2};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(twoSum(array, 6)));
    }

    public static int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        int oldValue = 0;
        int newValue;
        int currentValue;

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 1; i++) {
            currentValue = i;
            newValue = i + 1;

            if ((nums[currentValue] + nums[newValue]) == target) {
                return new int[]{currentValue, newValue};
            }
        }

        return new int[]{0, 0}; // we print out 0 0 if we can't find a solution
    }
```

Secondly, for time complexity, one trick I usually use is to look for loops in the code.

For my suggested code, in the worst case, it has to go through `N - 1 = O(N)` iterations and takes `O(1)` operation to execute each iteration. Therefore the time complexity is `O(N) * O(1) = O(N)`.

For your original code, it has to go through N iterations in the worst case, and takes approximately double the number of operations to execute each iteration compared to my code. However, the number of iterations is still `O(N)` and the number of operations per iteration is still `O(1)`, thus the time complexity of your code is also `O(N) * O(1) = O(N)`

**Note**

Having a loop doesn't always mean the number of iterations for that loop is `O(N)`. For example:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
   // do something
}
```

The time complexity for this loop is `O(1)`, since the number of iterations is always 100 and is independent of any input value

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i = i * 2) {
  // do something
}
```

The time complexity for this loop is `O(log2(n)) = O(log(N) / log(2)) = O(log(N))` (since log(2)) is a constant)